# How to stop activation addon if the main plugin is not activated

Tags: plugin-development, installation, deactivated-plugin

I´m writing an addon.
I would like in the install function to stop the activation if the main plugin is inactive.

```
class MyAddon {

     public function __construct(){
         register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'install' ) );
     }

     public function install(){
        if ( is_plugin_inactive( 'MainPlugin.php' ) ){
           //The addon has to be inactive
           // Notice for admin to prevent to active the main plugin before.
        }
    }

}
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

First of all, I discover that...

> you cannot use the `admin_notices` hook inside the activation hook function. [More details here](https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-create-admin-notice-on-plugin-activation/)

Thanks the link above, I found this solution :

```
class MyAddon {

    const ACTIVATION_ERROR = "foo-activation-error"

    public function __construct(){
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'install' ) );
        if( is_admin() ){
            add_action( "admin_init", array( $this, "init" ), 2 );            //priority 2 to load after the plugin
        }else{
             add_action( "init", array( $this, "init" ), 2 );
        }
    }

    public function init(){

        $has_to_be_deactivate = get_transient( self::ACTIVATION_ERROR );
        if( is_admin() ){
            if( $has_to_be_deactivate ){
                add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, "display_warning_no_activation" ) );
                deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );
            }
        }
    }

    public function install(){
        if ( is_plugin_inactive( 'MainPlugin.php' ) ){
            set_transient( self::ACTIVATION_ERROR , true );
    }

    public function display_warning_no_activation() {
        if( get_transient( self::ACTIVATION_ERROR ) ){
           ?>
           <div class="notice notice-error" >
              <p><?php echo esc_html__("Impossible to activate the addon : « My Addon », please check if the plugin « My Main Plugin » is active!", "addon-domain" ); ?></p>
          </div>
          <?php
       }
       delete_transient( self::ACTIVATION_ERROR );

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I dunno if this is **the** solution, but I'm looking at a similar challenge and this certainly seems to be a valid approach.